# Mysql query with IF -> THEN + IS NOT NULL throw me error?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, subquery, case

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    IF t1.person_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT person_contact.value
        FROM person_contact
        WHERE person_contact.person_id = t1.person_id AND
              person_contact.contact_id = 2
ORDER BY
   person_contact.last_change ASC
LIMIT 1 AS phone
FROM home_policy as t1 WHERE t1.id = 2
```

It throw's me error:

```
Unrecognized keyword. (near "IS" at position 30) 
Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOT NULL" at position 33) 
Unrecognized keyword. (near "THEN" at position 42) 
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 47)
```

I follow official doc where IF THEN is possible with NOT NULL

Comment: I agree with the compiler and also do not recognize this as valid MySQL code.  Can you add some sample data and desired results to your question?

Comment: This query is missin g `FROM` clause. Where do you define `t1` ?

Comment: Did you try writing the condition into round brackets?

Comment: @CMB it's edit.

Comment: It looks like the functionality you're looking for suits a CASE WHEN statement rather than an IF. IF has the form SELECT IF(condition, case1, case2).

Comment: @Jawi true, but later I want to add ELSEIF + ELSE

Comment: From the MySQL Reference Manual (the "official doc") it might not be clear but `IF .. THEN ... ELSE` is *not* valid SQL syntax; that syntax is valid only in the context of a MySQL stored program. i.e. in the body of a a `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE PROCEDURE`, or `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial problem with this query is that you cannot use the `IF` statement in this context; it is meant to be used in procedural context, not within queries. Instead, you could use `CASE` instead. Also, you need to wrap the subqueries in parentheses.

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    CASE WHEN t1.person_id IS NOT NULL THEN (
        SELECT p.value
        FROM person_contact p
        WHERE p.person_id = t1.person_id AND p.contact_id = 2
        ORDER BY p.last_change ASC
        LIMIT 1 
    ) END AS phone
FROM home_policy as t1 
WHERE t1.id = 2
```

That being said, I do suspect that you do not actually need a `CASE` expression. Unless you do have records in `person_contact` where `p.person_id` is `NULL` and `p.concat_id = 2`, your query could be simplified as follows:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    (
        SELECT p.value
        FROM person_contact p
        WHERE p.person_id = t1.person_id AND p.concat_id = 2
        ORDER BY p.last_change ASC
        LIMIT 1 
    ) AS phone
FROM home_policy as t1 
WHERE t1.id = 2
```

This might be a little less efficient, so make sure that you have an index on `person_contact(person_id, contact_id)`.

Comment: Can you provide example with multiple cases ?

Comment: Also `SELECT person_contact.value` should be `SELECT p.value` :)

Comment: @JoEark: ah yes, you are correct, thanks for spotting the typo, I fixed it.